# Easiest way to get online notifications

Tags: c, http, ftp

I have some C simulations running on my university servers and I am bored of having to sit and wait for them to end, considering they take quite a while. So I want to develop some kind of mechanism to know when they have ended. I was thinking of implementing an SMTP client with gmail, but considering I can't install anything on the system I wasn't able to add the SSL libraries to do so. I also can't remote access my desktop from outside campus. So once I leave I can't VNC y desktop.

So I was thinking if there is some way where I can rent some online space for free and be able to talk with the server through ftp or http and set add some text that the simulation has ended. That way I can check the space from home and know it ended.

I know the question is quite messy, and hope someone can help point me out to someideas. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend, [100webspace.com](http://www.100webspace.com/web-hosting/free-plan.html), it allows PHP and MySQL, all for free! Then just send data to it with [HTTP PUT and/or GET](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html) and view the results over the interweb.

My trawling of the web consistently turns up libcurl as the library of choice for interfacing C with HTTP commands. [This](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpput.html) is a sample using it with the PUT method.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be using a simple blog and updating it via HTTP. Just as an example, blogger supports [simple messages in XML](http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingPublicEntries). (REST would be my first choice but XML is not that bad)

Edit:

Tumblr does support [using an HTTP POST](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/es/api#api_write) without XML.